# How to iterate json object?

Tags: html, angular

I get the following value from external `API`([external API](http://13.126.181.94:8087/job_detail_description.php?job_id=19224&action=filter)).I think this  is `JSON` object. How to print this value in angular?

```
    {
    "job_details": {
        "job_title": "Cook",
        "company_email": "suryaadisiva@gmail.com",
        "industry": "Advertisement",
        "phone_no": "9746448899",
        "days_to_join_id": "2",
        "days_to_join": "Within a week",
        "participatestatus": "0",
        "job_type_name": "Full Time",
        "Qualficationprofileflag": "1",
        "jobview_count": "1",
        "company_id": "440",
        "job_add_date": "2019-02-26 09:33:36",
        "minimum_qual": "10th/SSLC",
        "Skills": "Chinese",
        "jobgender": "Female",
        "date_diff": 1,
        "experience": "2 - 3 years",
        "salary": "Rs 10,000 - 15,000"
         },
    "jobtoshowflag": "1",
    "jobdeleted": 0
}
```

The above is format from external `API`. what is the html syntax to print this in angular?

Comment: Your heading is totally different from what you are asking in the post. What you want to ask, how to  iterate the json or how to display it in the html or both?

Answer (score 0):

Save the response in a `variable` say `data`

```
data = {
    "job_details": {
        "job_title": "Cook",
        "company_email": "suryaadisiva@gmail.com",
        "industry": "Advertisement",
        "phone_no": "9746448899",
        "days_to_join_id": "2",
        "days_to_join": "Within a week",
        "participatestatus": "0",
        "job_type_name": "Full Time",
        "Qualficationprofileflag": "1",
        "jobview_count": "1",
        "company_id": "440",
        "job_add_date": "2019-02-26 09:33:36",
        "minimum_qual": "10th/SSLC",
        "Skills": "Chinese",
        "jobgender": "Female",
        "date_diff": 1,
        "experience": "2 - 3 years",
        "salary": "Rs 10,000 - 15,000"
         },
    "jobtoshowflag": "1",
    "jobdeleted": 0
    }
```

**HTML**

```
<h1>{{data.jobtoshowflag}}</h1>
<h1>{{data.job_details.job_title}}</h1>
```